# p:datatable displayed wrongly after ajax update

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, datatable

I have problem with a primefaces datable, I have a filter on a column and before to filter the result my datatable is displayed properly like this:

[image: good display]

When I choose a filter, the combobox of the filter is properly poulated:

[image: Display of the filter list]

A soon I choose the item for the filter, the results are properly filtered but I have a display of the datatable like this:

[image: Wrong display]

I just see the results who should be display in a datatable but the table is gone.

The code seems good and I don't see where is the problem:

```
<p:outputPanel autoUpdate="true" class="ui-g-12">
                <div class="card">
                    <h1>Gestion des noeuds</h1>
                    <h:form>

                        <p:dataTable value="#{nodeController.nodes}"
                                     var="node"
                                     tableStyle="table-layout: auto;"
                                     rowKey="#{node.nodeId}"
                                     paginator="true"
                                     paginatorPosition="bottom"
                                     paginatorAlwaysVisible="false"
                                     rows="15"
                                     widgetVar="nodeTable"
                                     filteredValue="#{nodeController.filterNodes}"
                                     editable="true"
                                     selection="#{nodeController.selectedNode}"
                                     selectionMode="single"
                                     paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}">

                            <p:column headerText="ID">
                                <h:outputText value="#{node.nodeId}"/>
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column headerText="Nom">
                                <h:outputText value="#{node.modeName}"/>
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column headerText="Description">
                                <h:outputText value="#{node.nodeDescription}"/>
                            </p:column>                  
                            <p:column filterBy="#{node.typeNodeId}" filterMatchMode="exact" headerText="Type">
                                <f:facet name="filter">
                                    <p:selectOneMenu onchange="PF('nodeTable').filter()">
                                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="filtre" itemValue="#{null}" noSelectionOption="true"/>
                                        <f:selectItems value="#{nodeController.nodeTypes}"/>
                                    </p:selectOneMenu>
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{node.typeNodeId}"/>
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column headerText="IPv4">
                                <h:outputText value="#{node.ipv4}"/>
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column headerText="IPv6">
                                <h:outputText value="#{node.ipv6}"/>
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column headerText="powwo agent">
                                <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{node.agentInstalled}"/>
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column headerText="Network status" style="text-align:center">
                                <p:graphicImage rendered="#{node.isconnected}" name="images/ConnectionStatus25.png" library="omega-layout" width="20"/>
                                <p:graphicImage rendered="#{!node.isconnected}" name="images/Siren-25.png" library="omega-layout" width="20"/>
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column>
                                <p:rowEditor/>
                            </p:column>

                        </p:dataTable>
                        <p:commandButton value="effacer"
                                         update="msg"
                                         actionListener="#{nodeController.deleteSelectedNode()}"                                                  
                                         style="width:auto;margin-bottom:10px;margin-top: 10px"/>
                    </h:form>
                </div>

            </p:outputPanel>
```

Did you already meet this issue with the rendered of a datable? Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: _"Did you already meet this issue with the rendered of a datable?"_ No never

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Effectively, your title and first sentence are not correct. It is not a bug in the datatable but a 'bug' in your code. You should not use `autoupdate="true"` on the `p:outputPanel` in this case. It updates all its content on each ajax update that happens inside it, including an ajax update during filtering. This latter **also** updates the datatable which means two conflicting updates. Off-topic:  If you'd created a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) , you'd have found this out during removal of code.

If you have this problem when you have an ajax listener on one of the filter/page/sort/... events on the datatable and you need the `autoUpdate="true"` on the panel for other events in the wrapping panel, you could also prevent the autoUpdate to happen for these specific events by adding a `ignoreAutoUpdate="true"` to the specific events. So e.g.

```
<p:ajax event="filter" ignoreAutoUpdate="true" ... />
```