# Primefaces Lazyloading renders rows as html on pagination

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, lazy-loading

I am building a single page application with **Primefaces 6.1**, **JSF 2.2** and running it on **Wildfly**, which has an option to search for users. Initial view renders only search panel with various filters and on click of search, user table will be queried and set of data is returned and then a block is rendered in the view which contains `datatable`. Below is the lazyloading code for search users.

```
public void getUsers(ActionEvent event) {
    //few lines to get filterData
    this.lazyUsers = new LazyDataModel<UserModel>() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        @Override
        public List<UserModel> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder,
                        Map<String, Object> filters) {

            filterObject.setStartCount(new Long(first));
            filterObject.setCountPerPage(new Long(pageSize));
            List<UserModel> list = userService.getUsers(filterObject);
            if (list != null)
                this.setRowCount(list.get(0).getTotalNumberOfRecords().intValue());
            RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance(); 
            if(context!=null)
                context.addCallbackParam("totalRecords", this.getRowCount());
            return list;
        }
    };
}
```

and here's my table view.

```
<p:outputPanel id="users" autoUpdate="true">
    <p:outputPanel rendered="#{users.displayusers}">
        <h5 class="title">
            <h:outputText value="#{msg.header_title}"></h:outputText>
        </h5>
        <p:dataTable id="userTable" lazy="true" paginator="true"
            rows="2"
            emptyMessage="#{msg.emtpymsg}"
            paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
            rowsPerPageTemplate="2,4,5"
            rendered="#{null != users.lazyUsers &amp;&amp; not empty users.lazyUsers }"
            value="#{users.lazyUsers}" var="user"
            rowIndexVar="userRow">
            <p:column headerText="#{msg.Name}">
                <h:outputLabel class="tdRow" value="#{user.name}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="#{msg.Phone}">
                <h:outputLabel class="tdRow" value="#{user.phone}" />
            </p:commandLink>
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="#{msg.Address}">
                <h:outputLabel class="tdRow" value="#{user.address}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="#{msg.Email}">
                <h:outputLabel class="tdRow" value="#{user.email}" />
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
    </p:outputPanel>
</p:outputPanel>
```

Everything renders when search happens but then when I paginate it searches for the next page data, and gets the next page data, but it renders it as plain html removing the datatable. On inspection of html, I can only see `tr`,`td` as response from server in network tab, and only contents within it are rendered directly into `div`. The datatable is not preserverd. Could anyone please let me know what's happening here.

I also tried to capture **page** event within `datatable` and added `update` value as

```
<p:ajax event="page" update="userContainer:userTable"></p:ajax>
```

but again it did not help. Hope to find some help.

**Update**

I noticed, this happens for any **ajax** operation through `datatables`, like, **filtering, sorting, rowsperpage** changed etc., Is there any way to identify on exactly what's wrong with this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Primefaces Datatable display bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44270955/primefaces-datatable-display-bug)

Comment: @Kukeltje Even though the problem was somewhat similar to him the solution was to use `process` in pagination `ajax` rather than `update`. I have updated my question and added an answer for the same. Thank you.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You change the value of `rendered` attribute. Try to encapsulate the `dataTable` ino another component, and re-render this outer component.

Also could be helpful if you place a dummy table in the template, that is always rendered, EG:

```
<p:dataTable disabled="true" />
```

This will make sure all the `dataTable` needed libraries are loaded at first load of your page...

Comment: `<p:dataTable disabled="true" />` I tried this but it did not help much. The result was same after ajax. Could you please add some detail on first point? It would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this problem was very simple infact.

I had to keep `<p:ajax event="page" update="userContainer:userTable"></p:ajax>` and rather than **update**, I had to use **process** and also with `ignoreAutoUpdate="true"`

```
<p:ajax event="page" ignoreAutoUpdate="true" process="userContainer:userTable"></p:ajax>
```

That fixed the issue. Hope this will be useful to someone in future.

Comment: Try without the process attribute. Should work identical... then the Q is a duplicate

Comment: @Kukeltje Well there is also `ignoreAutoUpdate` attribute which basically does the job and also, here my outercomponent never gets replaced. Well, even the problem is same, because of approach, the solutions is different.

Comment: Yes, **that part** is correct, I never said it was not. The process part however is unrelated. Then effectively the cause and functional solution are identical... prevent two updates to take place. I updated the other Q/A to also state that you can add an `ignoreAutoUpdate="true"`